# Does .NET Core 5 work with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me if .NET Core 5 works with VS Code on Linux (yet)? I followed the instructions to download and install .NET Core 5 as described in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/5.0/preview/5.0.0-rc.1-install-instructions.md) page.

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --channel=5.0/beta --classic
sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet
```

but when I try to list the installed SDKs, it doesn't show up.  All I see is the old version:

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.402 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/98/sdk]
```

The release notes for .NET Code 5 says it requires "Visual Studio 2019 16.8 Preview 2" but nothing about whether VS Code is supported.

Comment: Which version of linux do you have? In this article https://decatechlabs.com/how-to-install-net-core-on-ubuntu you can see which version  .net core is supported on  ubuntu

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.  The page you referenced has a cut-and-paste of the table from the official .NET Core web site.  It say 5.0 Preview is supported on Ubuntu 18.04 and even give instructions on how to install it but there is scant documentation on how to actually use it and nothing (that I've found) on how to use it with VS Code.

Comment: Just a thought did you upgrade your system to the latest version?

Comment: you already have one version on system and snap does not help to automatically install into existing folder . there is work around by manually copy and paste each version side by side . it did worked on our system and list both sdk side by side , i can answer in detail tomorrow. as far as using vs code , i have not tried that yet.